# Seaching for a String in a "String Pointer" - C Language

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to search for a string in a string pointer. I am not sure how to explain exactly what I am trying to achieve, but I will try my best.

Let's say I have two string pointers `char *p = "hello world"` and `char *q = "world"`, as `world` is in `hello world`, so I want to return a pointer `*start` that points to the `w` of `*p`. I hope that makes sense, if not then feel free to comment below.

**Note:** Unfortunately, I am not allowed to use any `string.h` library functions except `strlen()`, and also I am not allowed to use indexing in fact I am not allowed to use any square brackets `[]`.

P.S. Ignore all the `printf` as they are there to check where the program is going wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char *p = "hello world", *q = "world", *start;
    int i, count = 0;
    printf("%c\n", *p);
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(p); i++){
        printf("p: %c compares with q: %c\n", *p, *q);
        if ( *p == *q){ // tried: if ( p == q)
            start = p;
            printf("start: %s\n", start);
            while (*p == *q){ // tried: while ( p == q)
                printf("p: %c compares with q: %c\n", *p, *q);
                count ++;
                p ++;
                q ++;
                if ( count == strlen(q) ){
                    printf("Found it\n");
                    return *start;
                }
            }
        }
        p ++;
    }
    printf("Not Found\n");
    return 0;
}
```

As soon as it hits the `w` it prematurely exit out of the loop. I am not sure why its doing this? **This is my question**.

**Output:**

> p: h compares with q: w
>
> p: e compares with q: w
>
> p: l compares with q: w
>
> p: l compares with q: w
>
> p: o compares with q: w
>
> p:   compares with q: w
>
> Not Found

---

Edit:

`gcc -Wall filename.c` Compiler is not giving me any kinds of warnings/errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` loop is comparing `i` to the length of the string `p` points to, but since you keep changing `p`, that length keeps getting smaller, which is why the `for` loop ends about halfway through checking `p`.

If instead of using a counter `i` (which you don't do anything else with), you could instead replace the `for` loop with `while ( *p != '\0' )`: loop until you reach the end of `p`.

(Note: you can actually stop that loop as soon as then length of what is left is less than the length of the string `q` points to, but I'll leave that as an exercise.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would work:

```
char* find_pos_in_string(char* string, char* find) {
    for (char* s = string; *s != '\0'; ++s) {
        char* f = find;
        for (char* s_tmp = s; (*f == *s_tmp) && (*s_tmp != '\0') && (*f != '\0'); ++f, ++s_tmp);
        if (*f == '\0') return s;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

The first `for` loops through all possible starting positions in `string`. Second `for` compares each character from the two strings starting at `s`. It stops if it finds some character difference or if either string reaches its end. If the `find` string has reached its end, it means that all subsequent character match: we have found our position (i.e., `s`). If the outer loop finish without a match, `find` doesn't exist as a substring. We return `NULL`.